# С чего начинать Android разработку?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка

Хочу начать разрабатывать приложения под андроид, но не знаю с чего начинать, посоветуйте.
(Знаю Java)

Comment: с hello world -а по какому нибудь мануалу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С чего начать написание приложений под Android?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81/%d0%a1-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-android)

Comment: Начните как обычно с hello word

Answer (score 7):

Советую вам книгу - **Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (2nd Edition)**. Там простой английский (если хотите разрабатывать android приложения, то без знаний английского вам будет очень тяжело), хорошо описаны фундаментальные принципы, и обучение построено на разработке приложений. В первую очередь с помощью этой книги вы и научитесь целостной разработке приложений, и понимания Android, а не создания каких-нибудь отдельных компонент.
Если хотите рассмотреть, какой функционал есть в Android, то можете воспользоваться данным [сайтом](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/). Все распределено по категориям, и понятно описано.
Так же можете обращаться к [первоисточнику](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fundamentals.html), где есть масса полезной информации, там же присутствует официальный курс от разработчиков.

Answer (score 6):

Советую http://startandroid.ru/ru/ - по полочкам, шаг за шагом.

Answer (score 3):

Я начинал просто с чтения документации http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/index.html. Там в принципе все достаточно понятно расписано, если есть базовые знания Java и основных паттернов проектирования. Почти вся документация переведена на русский. 
Из видео обучалок хотел бы выделить https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIU76b8Cjem7oSU18zTKNfsyzrmf3Zubl.

Answer (score 1):

Заглянуть на сайт http://developer.android.com/ и ознакомиться с учебником для начинающих "Hello World". Это даст начальные знания о платформе.